# How can I solve "This app can’t open for Built-in Administrator account" with command line?

Tags: powershell, batch-file, cmd

Some of my applications are giving the following error when I try to run them:
"This app can’t open for Built-in Administrator account".
I found the following solution:
http://www.bleepingtech.com/windows-8-fix-this-app-cant-open-for-built-in-administrator-account/
Which works perfectly, but as I build my system using a script, I really need to perform the actions in the above solution using either command line commands or a Powershell script.
Does anyone know how I can perform the above actions using cmd/Powershell?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Why would you not use Group Policy for this?

Comment: I'd use any solution that works and can be implemented using command line :)

Comment: @shayelk You cannot do everything with a script as the solution in the link requires a restart.

Comment: @DavidPostill It is possible to restart using a Powershell script (my script already takes care of that)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why Tyler's solution didn't work, but based on his answer I managed to find the following:

```
reg add HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System\UIPI /ve /f /d "0x00000001 (1)"

reg add HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System /v FilterAdministratorToken /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f
```

somehow that does solve the issue

Answer (score 0):

If GPO is not a viable option, you could try something like the below (Requires Restart to Take Affect):

```
#Sets User Account Control: Admin Approval Mode for the built-in Administrator account to Enabled
New-ItemProperty -Path HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System\ -Name "FilterAdministratorToken" -Value "1" -Force


New-ItemProperty -Path HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System\UIPI\ -Name "(Default)" -Value "0x00000001(1)" -Force

# Use $env:COMPUTERNAME as value for -ComputerName if you want to restart local workstation
Restart-Computer -ComputerName SomeComputerName -Force
```

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't seem to work- the top command doesn't change the "admin approval mode..." setting

Comment: Not quite sure why that wouldn't work, Per [Technet Doc](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd835564(v=ws.10).aspx#BKMK_RegistryKeys) changing FilterAdministratorToken's value to "1" enables the setting.  Maybe the change doesn't reflect in the GUI. You rebooted after applying, correct?

Comment: I did, but I think it might have something to do with the registry type (REG_SZ vs REG_DWORD) and what FilterAdministratorToken should be vs what powershell sets it to be. I'm playing with it now, so hopefully I'll have an answer soon